# Aspiring to build a space rover from scratch. From where to begin?

Tags: robot, electronics, first-robotics

What fundamental concepts, beginner-friendly resources, or online courses would you recommend for someone starting with little to no background in robotics?

At first, I want to build a an autonomous wheeled rover which can navigate (using sensors) on rough surfaces and pick sample (with attached gripper on chasis) and safely drop it to a position marked with circle of any colour. It only communicate using Radio Frequency of legal range. No wire should be outside , it is totally remotely controlled. Power source should be battery.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this discourse post](https://discourse.ros.org/t/the-new-nasa-jpl-open-source-mars-rover-is-here/33650) will be of relevance to you.

Corresponding GitHub repository: https://github.com/nasa-jpl/open-source-rover